# Prove $\beta \vdash \alpha \rightarrow \beta$ using Cut, DT, IE, RAA and PIP

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

How am I proving this from Machover's text using Cut, DT, IE, RAA, and PIP. Does it involve using (i) $\lnot\alpha \vdash \alpha \rightarrow \beta$? For (i) I assumed $\lnot\alpha and \alpha$ then using IE to introduce $\beta$ and DT to finish off but here I don't know how to reach cleaner end form I've tried assuming $\lnot\alpha$ and referring to (i) to get the conditional but how do I get rid of $\lnot\alpha$ to end in a form I can use DT on $\beta$

CUT: $\alpha \vdash \beta$ and $\beta \vdash \phi$ then $\alpha \vdash \phi$

DT: $\phi, \alpha \vdash \beta$ then $\phi \vdash \alpha \rightarrow \beta$

IE: $\Gamma \vdash$ then $\Gamma \vdash \beta$

RAA: $\Gamma, \alpha \vdash$ then $\Gamma \vdash \lnot\alpha$

PIP: $\Gamma, \lnot\alpha\vdash$ then $\Gamma\vdash\alpha$

Comment: Hello and welcome to math.stackexchange. Please provide context to reach a maximum number of interested participants, and state what you have tried so far.

Comment: Can you please describe what exactly the rules of Cut, DT, IE, RAA, and PIP are?

Comment: @Bram28 sorry just included them

Comment: Are you allowed to assume $\alpha\vdash\alpha$? This is a DT away from $\alpha,\beta\vdash \beta$.

Comment: All these rules are *If* you have $... \vdash ...$ then .... .  So, none of these give you any $.... \vdash ...$ to start with.  As it is *nothing* can be proven from these rules ....

Comment: @Bram28 I would guess there has to be a rule like if $\alpha\in\Gamma$ then $\Gamma\vdash \alpha$

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen Yeah, that would be my guess as well .... :)  Hopefully the OP will realize as well that there must indeed be something else and look for that

Answer (score 2):

The proof presupposes a *deducibility* relation [see page 117] for which the basic properties hold.

In addition, we assume to have the *Deduction Theorem* available (as well as some additional rules).

See **Problem 7.4** [page 124] :

> Let $\vdash^*$ be the deducibility relation in a calculus that has *modus ponens* as a - not necessarily sole - rule of inference.
>
> Show that if $\text {Cut}$ and $\text {DT}$ hold for $\vdash^*$, then $\vdash^* \alpha \to (\beta \to \alpha)$ [...].

Thus :

> $\alpha, \beta \vdash^* \alpha$;
>
> > $\beta \vdash^* \alpha \to \beta$ --- from 1) by $\text {DT}$.

With a further application of $\text {DT}$ we will have $\vdash^* \beta \to (\alpha \to \beta)$, i.e. **Axiom scheme i** of $\vdash_0$ system [ref. page 117].

Finally consider **Problem 8.18** [page 128], where system $\vdash^*$ has *modus ponens* as well as $\text {Cut}, \text {DT}, \text {IE}$ and $\text {PIP}$. The problem asks to derive [*Peirce's law*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peirce%27s_law), that amounts to conclude the proof that the system $\vdash^*$ is complete for classical logic.